# Using outlook 2010 forms in other email clients?

Tags: forms, email, outlook, sendmail

I have created my own email client with C#,I can send and receive emails, i would like to send a customized outlook 2010 form (*or any customized form*) from my own email client.

My project has to send a form to a client, they can fill it out.
Send the form back with all the data on it.

I am very new to outlook, so if your answers could use very basic outlook lingo i would really appreciate that.

#### Questions...

1. Can i use outlook forms with other email clients?
2. How will my reply email look? with outlook forms when u receive a reply is it the filled out form?
3. Will outlook customized form's be the easier option for my idea? A good solid redirection would also be an appropriate answer, i would prefer not to find another dead end.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out look forms can't be read by other email clients like Gmail, yahoo and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A much more portable solution would be a an email message with a link to a web page with a form. Depending on what other clients you have in mind, this may be the only viable option. Microsoft's architecture is decidedly non-standard, but if you only target Windows users (who do not also have a mobile phone!) maybe you can pull something off within that silo / tar pit.